# Wrap a div element for a body's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to wrap up the body content inside a div dynamically. I tried the below code and i am getting, 'newDiv.append function is undefined'. I tried with setTimeout as well and checked after the jquery file loads made for loop to get loaded. Still getting the same error.

```
function initiate() {
    var jq_script = document.createElement('script');
    jq_script.setAttribute('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js');
    document.head.appendChild(jq_script);

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrapper');
    var bodyChildren = document.body.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) {
        newDiv.append(bodyChildren[i]);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
initiate();
```

And i tried this as well to wrap up the body's innerHTML with a div element.

```
function initiate() {
    var jq_script = document.createElement('script');
    jq_script.setAttribute('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js');
    document.head.appendChild(jq_script);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "wrapper";
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
        div.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
initiate();
```

This keeps on adding the wrapper element inside body. And the above script is inside iframe.

Any solution on this?

Comment: `newDiv.append` should be `newDiv.appendChild`. Additionally, since you're loading jQuery in the previous line `$("body > *").wrapAll($("<div id=\"wrapper\">"));` would be a lot neater

Comment: @RGraham: He/she would have to wait for it to load, however. :-) Also, doesn't `body > *` only select child *elements*? Not text nodes?

Comment: They'd need to wait for the DOM to load anyway surely? Good point about text nodes.

Comment: @RGraham `$("body").wrapInner("<div id='wrapper'>");` will be shorter.

Comment: @RGraham: Well, I don't know when `initiate` is being called. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. It's `appendChild`, not `append`.
2. Once that's out of the way, though, the other problem is in your loop: `childNodes` is a **dynamic** list, and so when you move a child out of `body` into `newDiv`, the list changes, making your indexes invalid.

   You can fix that by just looping, moving first child into your div, until the `body` runs out of children, then append the div:

   ```
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
   newDiv.id = "wrapper"; // You don't need or want setAttribute here
   var bodyChildren = document.body.childNodes;
   while (bodyChildren.length) {
       newDiv.appendChild(bodyChildren[0]);
   }
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
   ```

   Or actually, you don't even need the list, you can use `firstChild`:

   ```
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
   newDiv.id = "wrapper"; // You don't need or want setAttribute here
   while (document.body.firstChild) {
       newDiv.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
   }
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
   ```